# action cable subscribing locally, but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, puma, actioncable

I've been trying everything I can find online, and nothing is working. Hoping some fresh eyes will see the issue. This is my first time using ActionCable, and everything works great locally, but when pushing to heroku. my logs do not show any actioncable subscriptions like my dev server:

```
[ActionCable] [email@email.com] MsgsChannel is streaming from msg_channel_34
```

and when sending a message, I do  see `[ActionCable] Broadcasting to msg_channel_34:` but they are not appending, which I'm guessing means that the `received` method is not being accessed/called?

I do notice on heroku's logs it says `Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5000` where as dev it is listening at localhost:3000. Should I be pointnig towards my heroku app somehow?

Here are the relevant configuration files:

Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -p 5000  ./config.ru  
actioncable: bundle exec puma -p 28080  cable/config.ru  
redis: redis-server
```

***Thanks to the comment below, I am also trying. Still not working, but I can see that the port it's listening to is changing, making me believe it has something to do with the configuration? :

```
web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT  ./config.ru  
actioncable: bundle exec puma -p $PORT  cable/config.ru  
redis: redis-server
```

/cable/config.ru

```
require ::File.expand_path('../../config/environment',  __FILE__)  
Rails.application.eager_load!

ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins = ["http://localhost:3000"]  
run ActionCable.server
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['localhost:3000']
config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable"
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.web_socket_server_url = "wss://app-name.herokuapp.com/cable" 
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://app-name.herokuapp.com', 'http://app-name.herokuapp.com']
```

config/cable.yml

```
local: &local  
  adapter: async
  :url: redis://localhost:6379
  :host: localhost
  :port: 6379
  :timeout: 1
  :inline: true
development: *local  
test: *local


production:
  :url: redis:<%= ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] %>
  adapter: redis
```

`<%= ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] %>` is set, confirmed by running heroku config

routes.rb

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

Why is this working on dev, but not on heroku? I've been reading for hours, but can not figure it out. Thank you!!

UPDATE:
heroku logs:

```
2017-01-25T20:32:57.329656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -p 5000  ./config.ru`
2017-01-25T20:32:59.600554+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-01-25T20:32:59.600574+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
2017-01-25T20:32:59.600575+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2017-01-25T20:32:59.600577+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-01-25T20:33:02.375128+00:00 app[web.1]: profile controller
2017-01-25T20:33:02.588653+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-01-25T20:33:02.588446+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5000
2017-01-25T20:33:17.681469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-01-25T20:33:17.681469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-01-25T20:33:17.862118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-01-25T20:33:57.501746+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-01-25T20:33:57.501908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-01-25T20:33:57.630071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-01-25T20:33:57.642753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @Codingactive yes - I posted the solution below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was my host is the heroku app, but the requests were coming from the custom domain.

To solve:

`heroku config:set RAILS_HOST "http://www.example.com"`

And then in production.rb:

`config.action_cable.url = "wss://#{ENV['RAILS_HOST']}/cable"`

Answer (score 3):

Is your app name literally `app-name`? I suspect not. Odds are pretty good that these values...

```
config.web_socket_server_url = "wss://app-name.herokuapp.com/cable" 
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://app-name.herokuapp.com', 'http://app-name.herokuapp.com']
```

Need to be updated to use the actual public-facing URL you intend to connect to.

Comment: Ah yes, I just put that for the purposes of posting on SO :)

Comment: can someone tell me the difference between `config.web_socket_server_url` and `config.action_cable.url`? Which one gets used for what purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Your procfile suggests that you run puma with cable/cable.ru on port 28080. Also - file cable/config.ru shouldn't contain this line:

```
ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins = ["http://localhost:3000"]
```

You already configured this in config/environment/*.rb

Comment: I removed the above line, and it's still the same. I got the port 28080 in my Procfile, from a tutorial -- should it say something else besides 'actioncable: bundle exec puma -p 28080  cable/config.ru` ?  I added my heroku logs, incase that helps. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found the answer I needed [here: redis gem 4+ incompatibility "Specified 'redis' for Action Cable pubsub adapter, but the gem is not loaded"](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30527). Once I downgraded my redis to 3.1.0, worked perfectly.