# Actioncable works locally but not after deploying to Heroku - Rails & React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket, actioncable

I am using actioncable for a chat feature. It works perfectly when I test locally, but when I deploy to Heroku I get this error:

'WebSocket connection to 'wss://dg-automotive-portal- 
rails.herokuapp.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404'

production.rb:

```
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://dg-automotive-portal- 
  rails.herokuapp.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [
  'https://dg-automotive-portal.herokuapp.com/', 'http://dg- 
   automotive-portal.herokuapp.com/' ]
```

cable.yml:

```
  production:
  adapter: redis
  url:redis:MYURL
```

routes.rb has

```
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

And I have the redis gem installed. Does anyone know why this doesn't work when I deploy?

Javascript code called on componentWillMount:

```
  createSocket() {
      let cable = Cable.createConsumer('wss://dg-automotive-portal-rails.herokuapp.com/cable')
      this.chats = cable.subscriptions.create({
     channel: 'ChatChannel'
    }, {
      connected: () => {
        console.log("connected!")
     },
     received: (data) => {
       this.setState({
         chatLogs: [...this.state.chatLogs, data]
       })
     },
     create: function(chatContent, datetime, currentUser) {
       this.perform('create', {
        content: chatContent,
        time: datetime,
        user_id: currentUser
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Do you have Redis added to your Heroku instance? Also it would be helpful if you shared your configuration files.

Comment: Ahh never mind I see them now, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes i have it added to my heroku instance

Comment: It looks like the `config.action_cable.url` could be wrong. Try making the protocol `https` instead of `wss`. If this works I will add my answer so you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Please see same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860718/action-cable-subscribing-locally-but-not-on-heroku

Comment: @Nitsew that didnt seem to work, I am getting the same exact error 'action_cable.js:241 WebSocket connection to 'wss://dg-automotive-portal-rails.herokuapp.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404'

Comment: @gwalshington  that post doesnt help, I am making a request from the frontend which has a different url than my backend

Comment: We'll need to see the JavaScript you're using to make the websocket connection.

Comment: 1. Are you using Redis on the local machine as well (maybe the issue has nothing to do with Heroku)? 2. Do you have a custom URL for your app (it should be included in `config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins`)? 3. White space after `url:` in `url:redis:MYURL` might be nice...

Comment: @ArtOfCode ive added the javascript

Comment: @Myst 1. yes 2. yes i have custom URL and i added it in allow_request_origins but still get the same error. 3. white space made no difference, still the same error =/

Comment: Hi, did you manage to have action cable to work on Heroku? I have the same issue with Rails 4 and Ember.js. Our Js code is similar. I am trying to use `disable_request_forgery_protection=true` without success either. Also tried with standalone server.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that allowed_request_origins was not working like in my development mode. Indeed I had a regex taken from an environment variable so I did the same on heroku with no success. Replacing regex by the array of plain strings worked.